# Mysql: select from table and group by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

could you please help me with advanced SQL query?

I have records like this:

```
id, ProcessName,   Date
 1, Monitor.exe,   2016-05-01 17:00
 2, Monitor.exe,   2016-05-01 17:58
 3, Monitor.exe,   2016-06-11 15:43
 4, Monitor.exe,   2016-05-10 17:24
 5, Monitor2.exe,  2016-06-01 16:01
 6, Monitor2.exe,  2016-06-11 19:05
 7, Keeper.exe,    2016-06-01 13:02
 8, Keeper.exe,    2016-06-14 17:07
 9, Keeper.exe,    2016-06-14 11:00
```

The task is to display records from last two months grouped by process name and counted by entries and sorted by day. 
Like:

```
date,       ProcessName,   count(*)
2016-05-01, Monitor.exe,   2
2016-05-10, Monitor.exe,   1
2016-06-01, Keeper.exe,    1
2016-06-01, Monitor2.exe,  1
2016-06-11, Monitor.exe,   1
2016-06-11, Monitor2.exe,  1
2016-06-14, Keeper.exe,    2
```

Resolved!
final query is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%m-%d') as EventDate, ProcessName, count(*)
    FROM table_name 
WHERE
    date BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 day) AND NOW()
group by EventDate, ProcessName
order by EventDate
```

Thank you scaisEdge

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `WHERE`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my knowledge of SQL is very poor.

Comment: Learn by trying, failing and fixing. Not by asking some else to write it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a count and group by

```
select date(date), ProcessName, count(*)
from my_table 
group by date(date), ProcessName
order by date(date)
```